# Rails: how to enable PaperTrail auditing for tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, paper-trail-gem

I have a Rails 4.2 app and I'd like to keep audit history for tags by using PaperTrail.

Ideally the tags would be logged as if they were simply an attribute of the tagged model i.e. Model#tag_list.

I have enabled logging of Taggings by putting this in an initializer:

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tagging
    has_paper_trail
  end
end
```

... This does create versions for the Tagging but does not give me the desired behavior which is have the tags appear as simply a tag_list attribute of the tagged model.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. use Version Metatadata (https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata) 2. use Association Tracking (https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4b-associations)

Answer (score 1):

It probably makes sense to include versioning associations

```
PaperTrail.config.track_associations = true
```

after that, you can do for example

```
subject.versions.last.reify(has_many: true)
```

if you need "tag_list" you can write a wrapper that returns the list you need

```
def tag_list
  tagging.pluck(:title) #for_example
end
```